# How to force variables/inputs to be treated as different types in scheme?

Tags: types, type-conversion, scheme

I'm trying to write a recursive scheme function that parses a string and returns the sum of all numerical characters in the string.

I'm thinking I will need to do something like this:

```
(define (sumNums s)
    (if (null? s) 1
        (if (char-numeric? (car s))
            (+ ((car s) (sumNums (cdr s))))
            (sumNums(cdr s)))))
```

Whenever I try to run it with a string as the argument, it gives me an error saying it expects a pair. How do I indicate within the function that I will be giving it a string?

Further, I am having trouble passing (car s) as a character to the (char-numeric?) procedure. Just using a simple example function:

```
(define (isDigit c)
    (if(char-numeric? c)
        (display "is a number")
        (display "is not a number")))

(isDigit #\5)
```

If I explicitly include the #\ before the input in the function call, as above, it works correctly. But is there any way within the function to force it to interpret the input as a char?

```
(define (isDigit #\c)
    (if(char-numeric? c)
        (display "is a number")
        (display "is not a number")))
```

I tried the above function and it gives an error for unbound c. This:

```
(isDigit #\(5))
```

also does not work. So in scheme, I cannot even make it force the expression (5) to be interpreted as the character 5?

Thank you so much for the help, I am just starting to learn scheme and am finding it very unintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string->list` to convert your input string *s* to a list of characters:

```
(define (sum-nums s)
  (let ((s (string->list s)))
    ...
```

You will also need to convert the numeric character to a decimal digit, for which you will want `(- (char->integer (car s)) (char->integer #\0))`.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry. I missed the requirement that the solution be recursive. You will probably want two functions:

```
(define (sum-digits str)
  (sum-digits-aux (string->list str) 0))
```

The first function converts the string to a list of characters and calls the auxiliary function with a starting sum of 0. The second function computes the sum:

```
(define (sum-digits-aux cs sum)
  (cond ((null? cs) ...)
        ((char-numeric? cs) ...)
        (else ...)))
```

The `cond` has three clauses: the first clause terminates the recursion and returns the result; the second clause handles numeric characters; the third clause handles non-numeric characters.

I'll leave it to you to fill in the dots.

Comment: Thank you! I now have a function that scans a list, checks chars, and sums. How do I combine that with the string->list function? I tried putting the sumList function after the let statement you gave, and I get an error that the expected datatype is a pair: `(define (sumString s)
  (let ((s (string->list s))))
    (if (null? s) ;;body of sumList function, works when called on its own
        0
        (if (char-numeric? (car s))
            (+ 
               (- (char->integer (car s)) (char->integer #\0))
               (sumList (cdr s)))
            (sumList (cdr s)))))`